# stop PHP While loops and mySQL querys useing so much memory?

Tags: php, mysql, firefox

Ive noticed when working repeatedly with large amount of data in php/mysql the browsers memory usage increases very quickly.

eg running firefox 4, single tab open with just the app im testing is currently using over 800MB of ram.

The testing involved repeatedly loading over 500KB from mySQL via PHP while loops per refresh of the page or ajax call, I am assuming this is causing the memory buildup?

Is there a way I can reduce this?

Comment: The browser is not affected by anything that runs on your server - just by the data sent to it *by* the server. What gets sent exactly? That said, Firefox eating up 800 MB for no reason is not entirely unheard of :)

Comment: mainly data from mySQL with some html around it.

Comment: FF is known for having issues with using too much memory. Try your code in Chrome.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Parse less data (and send less HTML), it's the only solution to use less memory

Anyway to check the usage of memory you can use `memory_get_usage();`

Replying to your question title, to stop while loop

```
while($r=mysql_fetch_*($query)) {
    if (memory_get_usage()>YOUR_LIMIT_BYTE_HERE)  {
        echo 'red alarm here';
        break;
    }

}
```

Comment: `memory_get_usage();` is useless in this context; it's the web browser that's consuming 800 MB.

Comment: @Jacco, based on his script implemenation memory_get_usage can monitor how much data is going to be sent. (if he stores internally all records returned for example). Also if you read his title you can get why the function can be useful

Comment: `memory_get_usage();` reports the memory used by the PHP engine at the time of call. It has nothing to do with the returned dataset. As for your update, you should use `memory_get_peak_usage();` or you will get unexpected results. You really seem to be looking for a `$bytesSend = 0; while(yadayada){$bytesSend += strlen($r);}`

Comment: @Jacco: if you store the entirly dataset in an array where you think it will be stored?

Comment: where do you think all the *other stuff* is stored? like the constants you define, or the query-string in a variable? `memory_get_peak_usage()` reports the maximum amount of memory used, (including function, classes, variables, constants, pointers, etc, etc) by the PHP-engine, up to the moment of function call. The `memory_get_usage()` reports the same, but does not include memory freed by the garbage-collector. So yes, the size of you array does influence the reported memory usage, but the reported memory usage does not reflect the amount of memory used by your array.

Answer (score 1):

If you're returning **lots** of records from MySQL via ajax, then yes this could easily cause memory consumption in your browser to go up.

Depending on your browser and its implementation of Javascript, you may also have memory leaks - meaning that even after a page refresh, some of the memory allocated by the previous page is still in use.  Only closing the browser will likely cure that.